# Exception not raising in ipython but raised in python

Tags: python, exception, ipython

When I try to create an instance of class My_class it should return a ValueError when `var1` is not `"specific value"`

Class definition:

```
class My_class:
def __init__(self,var1):

    if var1 != "specific value":
        raise ValueError("api_type not equal to faq")
```

usage:

```
import the_file
mc = My_class(var1= "something wrong")
```

In a Python shell it does exactly that but with an IPython shell it does not even evaluate the if. 
Can someone explain me why?

Comment: There is not enough information to reproduce the problem. Make sure that in ipython you import from the expected location.

Comment: The location is correct, otherwise creating the object itself would give an error in python as well.
What extra information do you need except the class itself and the call to create an instance of it?  For me this was sufficient to reproduce the error in python but not in ipython (which is the problem)

Comment: Trying this out on https://try.jupyter.org/ and defining the class in the same text box, the notebook raises a ValueError as expected. Same running locally with `the_file` in the same directory I launched the notebook from. This points to something with the `import` - have you installed `the_file` in the python path somewhere? Or is there already a module with that name?

Comment: Indeed! I then wondered why it did not work in Spyder.. Reboot did make the error occur in both python and I python console. Sorry for the trouble! Thanks!